# Dynamic select list in Laravel with Form base bundle

Tags: php, laravel

Hi all i've been search for a while and can't find it in their documentation. does anyone know how to build a dynamic select list in laravel using the form-base plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public function user_options()
{
    return array('' => 'Choose a User') + User::lists('id', 'name');
}


{{ Form::select('user_id', UserWhateverForm::user_options(), UserWhateverForm::old('user_id')) }}
```

Comment: Is it possible to run a query to filter the returned list? If yes, how?

Comment: OK, I managed the do that with some help from the #laravel IRC channel. Something like: `User::where('id', 1)->lists('id', 'name')`.

Comment: @Shawn McCool Can you guide me the same to populate 3 select lists based on one another.

Country -> Load States based on country selected -> Load Cities based on States selected

Everything from Database

Answer (score -1):

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');
```

In the array you can dynamicly specify the options/value. The last option is the default value.

See the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/views/forms#drop-down-lists).

Comment: sorry but this isn't for dynamic data